# Select 2 colums together by max of one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple forum on my site which is almost perfect.  So close, but yet so far...

The following SQL is used to create the front page view of the forum where users can view threads and a summary of who is replying:

```
SELECT COUNT(forumtopics.forumtopicline)  AS totalthreads
  , forumtopicline
  , forumtopics.whenadded             AS threaddate
  , forumtopics.whoadded              AS author
  , forumtopics.title
  , COUNT(forumreply.forumtopic)      AS replies
  , MAX(forumreply.whenadded)         AS replydate
  , forumreply.whoadded               AS replier
 FROM forumtopics
   LEFT JOIN forumreply ON  forumtopicline = forumreply.forumtopic
WHERE  forumtopics.topic LIKE '%%'
   OR forumtopics.title LIKE '%%'
   OR forumreply.reply LIKE '%%'
GROUP BY forumtopicline
ORDER BY
   CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(forumreply.forumtopic) > 0 THEN MAX(forumreply.whenadded)
        WHEN COUNT(forumreply.forumtopic) = 0
             OR forumreply.forumtopic IS NULL THEN MAX(forumtopics.whenadded)
   END 
   DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Does the job almost perfectly.  This provides me with the date the thread was started, the thread author and the date of the last reply and it correctly ranks them with the post having the latest reply at the top.

The problem is with

```
MAX( forumreply.whenadded ) AS replydate, forumreply.whoadded AS replier
```

This returns the date of the last post to the thread but the first responder's name regardless of the date.  I am sure there must be a way to complete this rather elegant SQL to avoid application level manipulation.  Any help gratefully received.  Rather obviously, I need the forumreply.whoadded to be from the same row as the MAX(forumreply.whenadded)

DB=Mysql.  Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE forumtopics (
    forumtopicline     SERIAL
   ,title              VARCHAR(256)
   ,topic              TEXT
   ,whenadded          DATETIME
   ,whoadded           VARBINARY(128)
   ,whenaltered        DATETIME
   ,whoaltered         VARBINARY(128)
   ,inuse              BOOL
);

CREATE TABLE forumreply (
    forumreplyline     SERIAL
   ,forumtopic         BIGINT
   ,reply              TEXT
   ,whenadded          DATETIME
   ,whoadded           VARBINARY(128)
   ,whenaltered        DATETIME
   ,whoaltered         VARBINARY(128)
   ,inuse              BOOL
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    totalthreads,
    forumtopicline,
    threaddate,
    author,
    title,
    replies,
    replydate,
    (
        SELECT
            fr.whoadded
        FROM
            forumreply fr
        WHERE
            fr.forumtopic = forumtopicline
            AND fr.reply LIKE '%%'
            AND fr.whenadded = replydate
    ) as replier
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(forumtopics.forumtopicline)  AS totalthreads
      , forumtopicline
      , forumtopics.whenadded             AS threaddate
      , forumtopics.whoadded              AS author
      , forumtopics.title
      , COUNT(forumreply.forumtopic)      AS replies
      , MAX(forumreply.whenadded)         AS replydate
      , forumreply.whoadded               AS replier
     FROM forumtopics
       LEFT JOIN forumreply ON  forumtopicline = forumreply.forumtopic
    WHERE  forumtopics.topic LIKE '%%'
       OR forumtopics.title LIKE '%%'
       OR forumreply.reply LIKE '%%'
    GROUP BY forumtopicline
    ORDER BY
       CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(forumreply.forumtopic) > 0 THEN MAX(forumreply.whenadded)
            WHEN COUNT(forumreply.forumtopic) = 0
                 OR forumreply.forumtopic IS NULL THEN MAX(forumtopics.whenadded)
       END 
       DESC
) as tmp
```

Comment: Awesome.  That works perfectly.  Thank you so much.  For those seeking to use the SQL themselves, placing search text between the '%%' will allow the forum to have a search function too.